# Бульвар Л. Українки чи бульвар Лесі Українки?

Tags: власні-назви, орфографія, скорочення

Ще зі школи пам`ятаю, що, наче, псевдоніми не можна скорочувати на письмі.

Таким чином, ім`я Лесі Українки, яка в насправді була Ларисою Петрівною Косач, не можна зводити до "Л. Українка".
Але нещодавно побачила на одному з київських вказівників "бул. Л. Українки", тому піддала сумнівам свої здогадки. Можливо, це просто зумовлено браком місця на табличці і таке скорочення здійснене заля економії місця.

Чи справді можна скорочувати псевдоніми?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Згідно з книгою М. І. Лісового  [«Культура професійного мовлення: Навчальний посібник для студентів вищих медичних навчальних закладів.»](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=6WHrCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA143), **не можна скорочувати**:

1. Імена та імена по батькові (крім ініціалів):

   - не *Мих. Серг. Грушевський*, а *М. С. Грушевський* (як виняток — з одна­ковими 
     прізвищами: *Гр. Тютюнник* — *Григір*, бо є *Григо­рій Тютюнник*);
2. псевдоніми:

   - не *Ж. Занд*, а *Жорж Занд*,
   - не *Л. Українка*, а *Леся Українка*;
3. подвійні прізвища:

   - не *Б.-Хом'як*, а *Богачевська-Хом'як*,
   - не *Ж.-Стоша*, а *Жукевич-Стоша*,
   - не *К.-Яценко*, а *Кучук-Яценко*.

---

Є ще випадки, коли імʼя в людини справжнє, а прізвище вигадане. Наприклад: *Йосип Сталін* чи *Володимир Ленін*. Тоді імена скорочувати можна, бо вони таки справжні.

Інші джерела: [1](http://studopedia.com.ua/1_85478_pravila-skorochuvannya-sliv.html) —  [2](//gazeta.ua/articles/ukraine-newspaper/_ci-mozhna-skorochuvati-imya-lesi-ukrayinki/548288)
—  [3](http://helpstudenty.at.ua/publ/katalog_dlja_studenta/ukrainskij_jazyk/skorochuvannja_sliv_i_slovospoluchen/19-1-0-458)

**Отже, на вказівнику, все-таки, мало писати "бул. Лесі Українки".**

Comment: Цікаво, чому хтось поставив «мінус». По-моєму, гарна аргументована відповідь.

Comment: @Follower, а в чому різнобій? Можна скорочувати справжні імена до ініціалів (а пункт 1 каже, що навіть справжні не можна скорочувати не до ініціалів а-ля «Дмит. Петренко»), неспражні — не можна взагалі (за підсумком; приклад про Панаса Мирного автор прибрала, бо, ймовірно, вважає, що його помилково включили в категорію «не можна»). Мінусувати через Леніна/Сталіна взагалі дивно — що б не значили ці імена особисто для нас, з історії їх уже не викреслити (а Путіна у відповіді, до речі, й не було). По-моєму, відповідь варта «плюса». Щонайменше, вона підсумовує погляди, присутні в сучасній пресі.

Answer (score 5):

Хоча багато джерел стверджують, що псевдоніми не можна скорочувати (зокрема посібник М. Лісового «Культура професійного мовлення», зазначений у [іншій відповіді](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/3641) і деякі шкількі підручники), але, мені здається, ситуація не зовсім однозначна.

Ми [бачимо в «Google Книгах»](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%BB+%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%22+OR+%22%D0%BB+%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8%22), що псевдонім Лесі Українки скорочували до «Л. Українка» ще за її життя і періодично скорочували протягом усього часу донині. Невже це все помилки? А що робити, якщо невідомо, чи це псевдонім, чи ні? Коли хтось опублікував свою роботу з підписом Дмитро Петренко — і невідомо, чи це справжнє ім'я, чи ні, адже псевдоніми іноді для того й створюють, щоб сховати справджє ім'я. А що робити, коли автори самі підписують свій твір ініціалами, але несправжніми, наприклад, [М. Уманець і А. Спілка](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)?

По-моєму, сам факт того, що хтось обирає собі псевдонім, подібний до звичайного людського імені (Леся, Остап тощо), вже автоматично призводить до того, що його в певних випадках можна скорочувати (наприклад, не знаючи, псевдонім це чи ні). Тому, по-моєму, все значно складніше, і чи скорочувати псевдонім, визначається багатьма факторами, зокрема: тим, наскільки загальновідомо, що це псевдонім, тим, як сам носій ставиться до скорочення свого псевдоніму, тим, наскільки псевдонім схожий на звичне ім'я — тим, як історично склалося щодо конкретного псевдоніму.

Здається, не скорочувати псевдоніми насправді є більш схожим на стилістичну рекомендацію, аніж на суворе правило — **але я ніяк не можу це довести**.